# Задать значение по-умолчанию для поля класса

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток!

Как при помощи атрибута [DefaultValue()] задать значение по умолчанию полю имеющий тип "Class"?

Например:

```
public class MyClass
{
[DefaultValue("Здесь хотел назначить значение по-умолчанию")]
Public MyPropertyType MyProperty {get;set;}
}

public class MyPropertyType
{
    public int Key {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
    public int SomeKey {get;set}
}
```

Comment: Для чего? Для WPF дизайнера в Студии, или для сериализации?

Answer (score 1):

Может как-нибудь так:

```
public class MyClass
{
    Public MyPropertyType MyProperty {get;set;}

    public MyClass()
    {
         MyProperty = new MyPropertyType();
         MyProperty.Value = 1; 
    }

public class MyPropertyType
{
    public int Key {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
    public int SomeKey {get;set}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы не сможете передать в конструктор атрибута [`DefaultValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) конструкцию наподобие этой:

```
[DefaultValue(new MyPropertyType())]
public MyPropertyType MyProperty { get; set; }
```

по причине того, что параметры конструкторов атрибутов должны разрешаться на этапе компиляции и, согласно спецификации языка C#, они ограничены *константными значениями* следующих типов:

> - `bool, byte, char, double, float, int, long, sbyte, short, uint, ulong, ushort`
> - `System.String`
> - `System.Object`
> - `System.Type`
>
> Также допустимы одномерные массивы этих типов и типы перечислений (enums).

Comment: А что если сделать десериализацию из константного значения? Как это можно реализовать? Например, в defaultvalue указан текст, из которого потом десериализуется сам объект?